# Force list of lists into dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to turn a list of lists into a `data.frame`, but can't figure it out. Is there a standard function for this or something?

```
res<-lapply(1:5,function(x){list("RSI_MA"=x*2,"success_rate"=x,"cutoff_value"=(x+9))})
res  #WRONG
as.matrix(unlist(res),ncol=3,byrow=T) #WRONG
```

I would like the output to look like

```
RSI_MA success_rate cutoff_value
2      1            10
4      2            11
6      3            12
8      4            13
10     5            14
```

Comment: Base R doesn't have a s single function for this, but `data.table::rbindlist(res)` and `dplyr::bind_rows(res)` both work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
## can use `rbind`
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(res, as.data.frame))

#  RSI_MA success_rate cutoff_value
#1      2            1           10
#2      4            2           11
#3      6            3           12
#4      8            4           13
#5     10            5           14
```

Actually, this will work too:

```
## have to use `rbind.data.frame`
do.call(rbind.data.frame, res)
```

Comment: No need to specify `rbind.data.frame` explicitly - `rbind` will dispatch to the appropriate method, which it will know because you converted everything to `data.frame` objects.

Answer (score 3):

### tidyverse / dplyr answer

`dplyr::bind_rows()` works super well for these things.

```
res %>% bind_rows()
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  RSI_MA success_rate cutoff_value
   <dbl>        <int>        <dbl>
1   2.00            1         10.0
2   4.00            2         11.0
3   6.00            3         12.0
4   8.00            4         13.0
5  10.0             5         14.0
```