# List of list of lists (from API call) into data frame in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I know questions of this nature (convert lists into dataframes) have been asked before, however I'm running into a particular issue with a nested list of lists that I'd like to convert into a dataframe. The data I'm getting is from an API call in R, hence why I am dealing with this nested list of lists structure. Here's a small example of the API return object I am working with (5 games of sports data):

```
dput(soccer_data)
    list(structure(list(id = 1603158L, league_id = 779L, season_id = 914L, 
    stage_id = 1810L, round_id = 29156L, group_id = NULL, aggregate_id = NULL, 
    venue_id = 139L, referee_id = 656L, localteam_id = 607L, 
    visitorteam_id = 3639L, weather_report = NULL, commentaries = TRUE, 
    attendance = NULL, pitch = NULL, winning_odds_calculated = FALSE, 
    formations = structure(list(localteam_formation = "4-2-3-1", 
        visitorteam_formation = "4-1-4-1"), .Names = c("localteam_formation", 
    "visitorteam_formation")), scores = structure(list(localteam_score = 5L, 
        visitorteam_score = 1L, localteam_pen_score = 0L, visitorteam_pen_score = 0L, 
        ht_score = "1-0", ft_score = "5-1", et_score = NULL), .Names = c("localteam_score", 
    "visitorteam_score", "localteam_pen_score", "visitorteam_pen_score", 
    "ht_score", "ft_score", "et_score")), time = structure(list(
        status = "FT", starting_at = structure(list(date_time = "2017-03-04 05:30:00", 
            date = "2017-03-04", time = "05:30:00", timestamp = 1488605400L, 
            timezone = "UTC"), .Names = c("date_time", "date", 
        "time", "timestamp", "timezone")), minute = 90L, extra_minute = NULL, 
        injury_time = NULL), .Names = c("status", "starting_at", 
    "minute", "extra_minute", "injury_time")), coaches = structure(list(
        localteam_coach_id = 429924L, visitorteam_coach_id = 429940L), .Names = c("localteam_coach_id", 
    "visitorteam_coach_id")), standings = structure(list(localteam_position = NULL, 
        visitorteam_position = NULL), .Names = c("localteam_position", 
    "visitorteam_position")), deleted = FALSE), .Names = c("id", 
"league_id", "season_id", "stage_id", "round_id", "group_id", 
"aggregate_id", "venue_id", "referee_id", "localteam_id", "visitorteam_id", 
"weather_report", "commentaries", "attendance", "pitch", "winning_odds_calculated", 
"formations", "scores", "time", "coaches", "standings", "deleted"
)), structure(list(id = 1603159L, league_id = 779L, season_id = 914L, 
    stage_id = 1810L, round_id = 29156L, group_id = NULL, aggregate_id = NULL, 
    venue_id = 113L, referee_id = 3614L, localteam_id = 577L, 
    visitorteam_id = 75L, weather_report = NULL, commentaries = FALSE, 
    attendance = NULL, pitch = NULL, winning_odds_calculated = FALSE, 
    formations = structure(list(localteam_formation = "4-2-3-1", 
        visitorteam_formation = "4-2-3-1"), .Names = c("localteam_formation", 
    "visitorteam_formation")), scores = structure(list(localteam_score = 1L, 
        visitorteam_score = 1L, localteam_pen_score = 0L, visitorteam_pen_score = 0L, 
        ht_score = "1-0", ft_score = "1-1", et_score = NULL), .Names = c("localteam_score", 
    "visitorteam_score", "localteam_pen_score", "visitorteam_pen_score", 
    "ht_score", "ft_score", "et_score")), time = structure(list(
        status = "FT", starting_at = structure(list(date_time = "2017-03-04 22:00:00", 
            date = "2017-03-04", time = "22:00:00", timestamp = 1488664800L, 
            timezone = "UTC"), .Names = c("date_time", "date", 
        "time", "timestamp", "timezone")), minute = 90L, extra_minute = NULL, 
        injury_time = NULL), .Names = c("status", "starting_at", 
    "minute", "extra_minute", "injury_time")), coaches = structure(list(
        localteam_coach_id = 455860L, visitorteam_coach_id = 176760L), .Names = c("localteam_coach_id", 
    "visitorteam_coach_id")), standings = structure(list(localteam_position = NULL, 
        visitorteam_position = NULL), .Names = c("localteam_position", 
    "visitorteam_position")), deleted = FALSE), .Names = c("id", 
"league_id", "season_id", "stage_id", "round_id", "group_id", 
"aggregate_id", "venue_id", "referee_id", "localteam_id", "visitorteam_id", 
"weather_report", "commentaries", "attendance", "pitch", "winning_odds_calculated", 
"formations", "scores", "time", "coaches", "standings", "deleted"
)), structure(list(id = 1603160L, league_id = 779L, season_id = 914L, 
    stage_id = 1810L, round_id = 29156L, group_id = NULL, aggregate_id = NULL, 
    venue_id = 28L, referee_id = 555L, localteam_id = 413L, visitorteam_id = 583L, 
    weather_report = NULL, commentaries = FALSE, attendance = 23554L, 
    pitch = NULL, winning_odds_calculated = FALSE, formations = structure(list(
        localteam_formation = "4-4-1-1", visitorteam_formation = "4-4-2"), .Names = c("localteam_formation", 
    "visitorteam_formation")), scores = structure(list(localteam_score = 1L, 
        visitorteam_score = 2L, localteam_pen_score = 0L, visitorteam_pen_score = 0L, 
        ht_score = "0-0", ft_score = "1-2", et_score = NULL), .Names = c("localteam_score", 
    "visitorteam_score", "localteam_pen_score", "visitorteam_pen_score", 
    "ht_score", "ft_score", "et_score")), time = structure(list(
        status = "FT", starting_at = structure(list(date_time = "2017-03-05 00:00:00", 
            date = "2017-03-05", time = "00:00:00", timestamp = 1488672000L, 
            timezone = "UTC"), .Names = c("date_time", "date", 
        "time", "timestamp", "timezone")), minute = 90L, extra_minute = NULL, 
        injury_time = NULL), .Names = c("status", "starting_at", 
    "minute", "extra_minute", "injury_time")), coaches = structure(list(
        localteam_coach_id = 429914L, visitorteam_coach_id = 429917L), .Names = c("localteam_coach_id", 
    "visitorteam_coach_id")), standings = structure(list(localteam_position = NULL, 
        visitorteam_position = NULL), .Names = c("localteam_position", 
    "visitorteam_position")), deleted = FALSE), .Names = c("id", 
"league_id", "season_id", "stage_id", "round_id", "group_id", 
"aggregate_id", "venue_id", "referee_id", "localteam_id", "visitorteam_id", 
"weather_report", "commentaries", "attendance", "pitch", "winning_odds_calculated", 
"formations", "scores", "time", "coaches", "standings", "deleted"
)), structure(list(id = 1603161L, league_id = 779L, season_id = 914L, 
    stage_id = 1810L, round_id = 29156L, group_id = NULL, aggregate_id = NULL, 
    venue_id = 411L, referee_id = 274L, localteam_id = 1062L, 
    visitorteam_id = 111L, weather_report = NULL, commentaries = FALSE, 
    attendance = NULL, pitch = NULL, winning_odds_calculated = FALSE, 
    formations = structure(list(localteam_formation = "4-2-3-1", 
        visitorteam_formation = "3-5-2"), .Names = c("localteam_formation", 
    "visitorteam_formation")), scores = structure(list(localteam_score = 0L, 
        visitorteam_score = 0L, localteam_pen_score = 0L, visitorteam_pen_score = 0L, 
        ht_score = "0-0", ft_score = "0-0", et_score = NULL), .Names = c("localteam_score", 
    "visitorteam_score", "localteam_pen_score", "visitorteam_pen_score", 
    "ht_score", "ft_score", "et_score")), time = structure(list(
        status = "FT", starting_at = structure(list(date_time = "2017-03-05 00:30:00", 
            date = "2017-03-05", time = "00:30:00", timestamp = 1488673800L, 
            timezone = "UTC"), .Names = c("date_time", "date", 
        "time", "timestamp", "timezone")), minute = 90L, extra_minute = NULL, 
        injury_time = NULL), .Names = c("status", "starting_at", 
    "minute", "extra_minute", "injury_time")), coaches = structure(list(
        localteam_coach_id = 456638L, visitorteam_coach_id = 516577L), .Names = c("localteam_coach_id", 
    "visitorteam_coach_id")), standings = structure(list(localteam_position = NULL, 
        visitorteam_position = NULL), .Names = c("localteam_position", 
    "visitorteam_position")), deleted = FALSE), .Names = c("id", 
"league_id", "season_id", "stage_id", "round_id", "group_id", 
"aggregate_id", "venue_id", "referee_id", "localteam_id", "visitorteam_id", 
"weather_report", "commentaries", "attendance", "pitch", "winning_odds_calculated", 
"formations", "scores", "time", "coaches", "standings", "deleted"
)), structure(list(id = 1603162L, league_id = 779L, season_id = 914L, 
    stage_id = 1810L, round_id = 29157L, group_id = NULL, aggregate_id = NULL, 
    venue_id = 11573L, referee_id = 370L, localteam_id = 179L, 
    visitorteam_id = 641L, weather_report = NULL, commentaries = FALSE, 
    attendance = NULL, pitch = NULL, winning_odds_calculated = FALSE, 
    formations = structure(list(localteam_formation = "4-2-3-1", 
        visitorteam_formation = "4-3-1-2"), .Names = c("localteam_formation", 
    "visitorteam_formation")), scores = structure(list(localteam_score = 1L, 
        visitorteam_score = 0L, localteam_pen_score = 0L, visitorteam_pen_score = 0L, 
        ht_score = "0-0", ft_score = "1-0", et_score = NULL), .Names = c("localteam_score", 
    "visitorteam_score", "localteam_pen_score", "visitorteam_pen_score", 
    "ht_score", "ft_score", "et_score")), time = structure(list(
        status = "FT", starting_at = structure(list(date_time = "2017-03-05 02:00:00", 
            date = "2017-03-05", time = "02:00:00", timestamp = 1488679200L, 
            timezone = "UTC"), .Names = c("date_time", "date", 
        "time", "timestamp", "timezone")), minute = 90L, extra_minute = NULL, 
        injury_time = NULL), .Names = c("status", "starting_at", 
    "minute", "extra_minute", "injury_time")), coaches = structure(list(
        localteam_coach_id = 524071L, visitorteam_coach_id = 261458L), .Names = c("localteam_coach_id", 
    "visitorteam_coach_id")), standings = structure(list(localteam_position = NULL, 
        visitorteam_position = NULL), .Names = c("localteam_position", 
    "visitorteam_position")), deleted = FALSE), .Names = c("id", 
"league_id", "season_id", "stage_id", "round_id", "group_id", 
"aggregate_id", "venue_id", "referee_id", "localteam_id", "visitorteam_id", 
"weather_report", "commentaries", "attendance", "pitch", "winning_odds_calculated", 
"formations", "scores", "time", "coaches", "standings", "deleted"
)))
```

soccer_data has 5 games of MLS soccer data, and here is what I am currently doing to convert this into a dataframe:

```
# grab the "scores" info from the nested list $scores (from each game)
season_scores <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(soccer_data)) {  
  game_scores <- as.data.frame(t(unlist(soccer_data[[i]]$scores)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  game_scores$date <- as.Date(soccer_data[[i]]$time$starting_at$date)
  season_scores <- rbind.fill(season_scores, game_scores)
}
season_scores <- season_scores %>% readr::type_convert()

# create df of the game scores, add the season scores, and drop the bad cols
season_boxscores <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, soccer_data), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  dplyr::select(-one_of(c('scores', 'group_id', 'aggregate_id', 'time', 'standings'))) %>%
  cbind(season_scores) %>%
  readr::type_convert()
```

Unfortunately, the issue with this approach is that the very last type_convert() function call doesn't do what I'd like, and the resulting season_boxscores dataframe has columns whose classes are mostly of class == list.

```
# check yourself
sapply(season_boxscores, class)
```

My questions then are:

1. How can I do this so that the classes of all of the columns in season_boxscores are not all class == list? And also,
2. Am I doing this (converting from list of lists of lists) in the best way possible, with the do.call, rbind, and as.data.frame?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It would be particularly nice if all of the nested lists (in this case, soccer_data has a few: formations, scores, time, coaches, standings) sort of unnested themselves, in the same way that I unnested them in the for loop for scores.

EDIT 2: Sorry for sharing such a large list object for only 5 games. In a list of lists, or big nested object like this, I actually do not know how to remove the same item from each nested list, which I would've done for this post. (ie remove league_id, round_id, etc. from each of soccer_data[[i]]). If anyone knows how to do that either, would be great to know!

EDIT 3: because soccer_data isnt simply a list of lists, but rather a list of list of lists (with other, non-list objects in each list of lists), none of the solutions here - [Force list of lists into dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966071/force-list-of-lists-into-dataframe) - work on soccer_data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still trying to learn this stuff too. I tested a million things and this was the simplest I could come up with:

```
library(tidyverse)
soccer_data %>% 
  map(unlist) %>% 
  map(t) %>% 
  map(as_tibble) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

The idea: take your list `soccer_data`, map `unlist` to every element (so it unlists at the second level, which means it keeps all the games in separate elements of the top-most list). Then use map transpose `t` to turn the list to a thing that looks like a row, then convert it to a `tibble`, then `bind_rows` them altogether.

The result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 30
  id      league_id season_id stage_id round_id venue_id referee_id localteam_id
  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>      <chr>       
1 1603158 779       914       1810     29156    139      656        607         
2 1603159 779       914       1810     29156    113      3614       577         
3 1603160 779       914       1810     29156    28       555        413         
4 1603161 779       914       1810     29156    411      274        1062        
5 1603162 779       914       1810     29157    11573    370        179         
# ... with 22 more variables: visitorteam_id <chr>, commentaries <chr>,
#   winning_odds_calculated <chr>, formations.localteam_formation <chr>,
#   formations.visitorteam_formation <chr>, scores.localteam_score <chr>,
#   scores.visitorteam_score <chr>, scores.localteam_pen_score <chr>,
#   scores.visitorteam_pen_score <chr>, scores.ht_score <chr>, scores.ft_score <chr>,
#   time.status <chr>, time.starting_at.date_time <chr>, time.starting_at.date <chr>,
#   time.starting_at.time <chr>, time.starting_at.timestamp <chr>,
#   time.starting_at.timezone <chr>, time.minute <chr>,
#   coaches.localteam_coach_id <chr>, coaches.visitorteam_coach_id <chr>,
#   deleted <chr>, attendance <chr>
```

Does that look right? Good luck!

Comment: ill give this a shot now thanks! - what tidyverse library is map from? edit: its from purrr

Comment: I come back to this post like once a month to reuse this code when I'm working with a different API. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

How about the following base R only approach (using `unlist`):

1. Collapse list of list of list to `list` of `char` vectors:

   ```
   # Collapse list of list of list to list of character vectors
   lst <- lapply(soccer_data, unlist);
   ```
2. Make sure that all list entries have the same keys. For example, only `list` entry 3 of your sample data has key `attendance`.

   ```
   # Make sure that all list entries have values for the same keys
   keys <- unique(unlist(lapply(lst, names)));
   ```
3. Fill missing key entries with `NA`

   ```
   # Fill missing entries with NULL
   lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) x[match(keys, names(x))]);
   ```
4. `rbind` into `data.frame`:

   ```
   # Combind in dataframe
   df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lst);
   colnames(df) <- keys;


   df;
   #id league_id season_id stage_id round_id venue_id referee_id
   #1 1603158       779       914     1810    29156      139        656
   #2 1603159       779       914     1810    29156      113       3614
   #3 1603160       779       914     1810    29156       28        555
   #4 1603161       779       914     1810    29156      411        274
   #5 1603162       779       914     1810    29157    11573        370
   #localteam_id visitorteam_id commentaries winning_odds_calculated
   #1          607           3639         TRUE                   FALSE
   #2          577             75        FALSE                   FALSE
   #3          413            583        FALSE                   FALSE
   #4         1062            111        FALSE                   FALSE
   #5          179            641        FALSE                   FALSE
   #formations.localteam_formation formations.visitorteam_formation
   #1                        4-2-3-1                          4-1-4-1
   #2                        4-2-3-1                          4-2-3-1
   #3                        4-4-1-1                            4-4-2
   #4                        4-2-3-1                            3-5-2
   #5                        4-2-3-1                          4-3-1-2
   #scores.localteam_score scores.visitorteam_score scores.localteam_pen_score
   #1                      5                        1                          0
   #2                      1                        1                          0
   #3                      1                        2                          0
   #4                      0                        0                          0
   #5                      1                        0                          0
   #scores.visitorteam_pen_score scores.ht_score scores.ft_score time.status
   #1                            0             1-0             5-1          FT
   #2                            0             1-0             1-1          FT
   #3                            0             0-0             1-2          FT
   #4                            0             0-0             0-0          FT
   #5                            0             0-0             1-0          FT
   #time.starting_at.date_time time.starting_at.date time.starting_at.time
   #1        2017-03-04 05:30:00            2017-03-04              05:30:00
   #2        2017-03-04 22:00:00            2017-03-04              22:00:00
   #3        2017-03-05 00:00:00            2017-03-05              00:00:00
   #4        2017-03-05 00:30:00            2017-03-05              00:30:00
   #5        2017-03-05 02:00:00            2017-03-05              02:00:00
   #time.starting_at.timestamp time.starting_at.timezone time.minute
   #1                 1488605400                       UTC          90
   #2                 1488664800                       UTC          90
   #3                 1488672000                       UTC          90
   #4                 1488673800                       UTC          90
   #5                 1488679200                       UTC          90
   #coaches.localteam_coach_id coaches.visitorteam_coach_id deleted attendance
   #1                     429924                       429940   FALSE       <NA>
   #2                     455860                       176760   FALSE       <NA>
   #3                     429914                       429917   FALSE      23554
   #4                     456638                       516577   FALSE       <NA>
   #5                     524071                       261458   FALSE       <NA>
   ```

If you remove all the excess text/explanations, this is quite short.

---

### Update

Unfortunately, column types are lost as a result of `unlist`. You can convert `factors` back to `numeric` in the following way:

```
# Smart-convert to numeric
is.num <- apply(df, 2, function(x) {
    x <- x[!is.na(x)];
    all(suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x)))));
})
df[, is.num] <- apply(df[, is.num], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)));
```

It's a bit messy but works.

Comment: I dont like that the columns are all class == "factor", since readr::type_convert() wont work to convert the column types

Comment: @Canovice Yes, you're right; I hadn't realised that all columns got turned into `factors`. I've included an update to convert "numeric" `factors` back to `numeric`.